# How to check field is empty after fetching from database?

Tags: php

I am storing images in a column, I just want to hide img tag when the image field is empty in  a table.

```
$imgResult= explode('**',$resultArray['mediaGallery']);
if(empty($imgResult)===true){
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
          $(document).ready(function(e) {
              $('.display').css('display','none');
          });
          </script>";
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($imgResult)` and check what is in the variable when you "think" it should be empty. To check if your thoughts are right. It could be possible it is not empty at all!

Comment: And why are you exploding on '**', I think your database is not optimal. And you could better use http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php since this is more structured if you want to store an array in 1 column in your db.

Comment: I have store multiple images in a database,I just wanted first image to display so i have explode and i have to check if image column is empty r not if its empty img tag should hide.

Comment: @user1586851 still, do not explode. Store every image in a separate row in a new table, or store it in an array which you can json_encode. Your solution is wrong. Now when you decode the json string, you have more controll and you are sure the output is what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shoul check `if($imgResult == null)` instead of `empty`. Because even when there's nothing in the table field you're selecting from, the variable won't be empty; it will be set to null.

Comment: `$var = null; var_dump(empty($var)); //Output "bool(true)"` So your answer does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

One better way :-

```
if( true == is_null( $imgResult ) ) {
}
```

Comment: Why would you compare it to `== true`, `is_null` returns `true` or `false`, so why would you compare it? Now you are saying: `true == false` or `true == true`. Seems kinda wrong, right?

Comment: @Jelmer Why not simply compare variable to `null`?

Comment: You are right. I used to this standard. But is_null() is all right.